# Stop function execution if HTTP request succeed ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

My requirement is if the request succeeds then it cannot execute again. But now it is calling every time:

```
public async Task Send(CancellationToken token)
{
    logger.LogInformation("E-mail background delivery started");

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {

        try
        {
            if (FullUrl != null)
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, FullUrl);

                // Let's wait for a message to appear in the queue
                // If the token gets canceled, then we'll stop waiting
                // since an OperationCanceledException will be thrown

                var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

                // token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request, token).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"E-mail sent to");
                }
            }


            //as soon as a message is available, we'll send it
            logger.LogInformation($"E-mail sent to");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            //We need to terminate the delivery, so we'll just break the while loop
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            #warning Implement a retry mechanism or else this message will be lost
            logger.LogWarning($"Couldn't send an e-mail to");
            break;
        }
    }

    logger.LogInformation("E-mail background delivery stopped");
}
```

Comment: I think it's unclear what you are asking for, could you please clarify your question.

Comment: so you want to exit the `while` loop if the request was successful? why not just change the flag of your loop to `while (!requestSuccessful) { if (!token.IsCancellationRequested { // ... } }` and set `requestSuccessful` to `true` if `response.IsSuccessStatuscode`?

Answer (score 0):

Try code below to append variable to indicate whether the reposne is success.

```
public async Task Send(CancellationToken token)
{
    logger.LogInformation("E-mail background delivery started");
    bool IsSuccess = false;
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested && !IsSuccess)
    {

        try
        {
            if (FullUrl != null)
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, FullUrl);

                // Let's wait for a message to appear in the queue
                // If the token gets canceled, then we'll stop waiting
                // since an OperationCanceledException will be thrown

                var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

                // token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request, token).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"E-mail sent to");
                }
                else
                {
                    IsSuccess = true;
                }
            }


            //as soon as a message is available, we'll send it
            logger.LogInformation($"E-mail sent to");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            //We need to terminate the delivery, so we'll just break the while loop
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            #warning Implement a retry mechanism or else this message will be lost
            logger.LogWarning($"Couldn't send an e-mail to");
            break;
        }
    }

    logger.LogInformation("E-mail background delivery stopped");
}
```